# Templatetag returns None

Tags: python, django, templatetags

**My tag.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.simple_tag()
def validator(data2, b):
  nop = False
  for data1 in b:
    if data2.pk == data1.mix_id:
      nop = True
    else:
      correct=data2
  if nop :
    pass
  else:
    print(correct)
    return correct
```

**My template.html**

```
{% for data2 in mix.qs %}
  {% validator data2 vuelos.qs as data3 %}
  {{data3}}
```

**The Output of {{data3}}**

```
None
```

The output of the print in the tag.py file is a list, its exactly what I want to get saved on data3 but the code only exits None. Any sugestions?

Comment: In `validator`, what would happen if `b` is `None`? The `else` clause would execute and return `correct` which is `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is in the tag.py

```
if not nop :
  return correct
```